# Why are PHP "super global" variables called "super global"?

Tags: php

My friend tells me that they are called "super global" because they hold data which is available before php starts.

eg:

- in a url: `?fname=somename`, the data in `$_GET` is available outside PHP, in the URL before PHP starts.
- in a form: `<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="somename" />`, the data in `$_POST` is available in posted data before PHP starts.
- in a cookie: `$_COOKIE` data is saved somewhere in your computer, so it is available before PHP starts.

Is my friend right? if he is wrong then **what is the difference between a superglobal to just global variable?**

Comment: What do you mean `before php starts`?

Comment: thats what he said like in cookies

Comment: I have edited your question based on my understanding of what you meant. Please revert the edit if I misunderstood. I expect you are getting downvoted because your question is about a very basic concept of the language, but I'm hoping that clearing up the way it is phrased helps people to understand where you are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

No. They are "superglobal" because they are available in all scopes, without needing to import them into the current scope by using the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword.

Comment: if there is anything else you want cleared up, feel free to ask